# ActionListener get's default values

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, initialization

I'm implementing a simple application in Java. I'm using the MVC module for the app. The problem is that when my `Controller` creates the objects of the `View` and the `Model`, when trying to use a simple get method I get the defaults values and not the new ones, that I inserted in the UI. Here is a code exmaple:

View:

```
public class Client extends JFrame {
    private float ammount;
    private JButton calculateButton;
    ...
    public void startUI(ActionListener listener) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Client frame = new Client(listener);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    public Client(ActionListener listener) {
    ...
                        ammount = 10;
    ...
    calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    calculateButton.addActionListener(listener);
        add(calculateButton);
    ...
    public float getAmmount() {
        return (float) this.ammount;
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    private float result;
    private Server server = new Server();
    private Client client = new Client(this);

    public Controller() {
        server.rateParser();
        client.startUI(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result = client.getAmmount();
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Program {

    // Main function
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
    }

}
```

So far so good, however, when I click the button and the action event triggers, 
the `getAmmount` method returns -1, which is the default value. Same goes for all the getters in the `Client` class. Does any one knows why is this happening?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: You're instantiating the Client instance with the  `Client(CurrencyParser, ActionListener)` constructor, but your code snippet shows the `Client(ActionListener)` constructor.  Could this be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove that piece of code. Fixed now.

Comment: Correct the title while at it.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing 2 clients.

**First time** is in the call inside `main`

```
Controller controller = new Controller();
```

When you initialize a class, all its members are initialized too. Since `Client` is a member of `Controller`:

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    private Client client = new Client(this); // 1st initialization
}
```

it is initialized with a `new Controller()` call.

**Second time** is the call in the constructor

```
public Controller() {

    server.rateParser();
    client.startUI(this); // <---- here
}
```

Leaving the fuzz out of `startUI`, it is:

```
public void startUI(ActionListener listener) {

    Client frame = new Client(listener); // 2nd initialization
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Since `actionPerformed` is inside `Controller`, it is its field `client` that is called in `result = client.getAmmount();`. That one is remained untouched throughout the program's lifetime and thus returns the defaults (which were created in its initialization). However, the client you display is the second one, `frame`, for which you call `frame.setVisible(true);`. That one is modified, but its values are never read.