# int and boolean not changing after action performed

Tags: java, swing

I copied all of the relevant code below, and my problem is that after running the action performed (which is connected to a button) the values I tried to change in the action performed didn't actually change.

I put a sout(ques) at the end of the action performed and I can see the change in value but when I move outside of it, it reverts back to the 0;

```
public class GameRunner extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private int x=50,y=600;
    private Ball b = new Ball(x,y);
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean correct , incorrect;
    private   JButton button;
    private JTextField f;
    private int ques = 0;
    private String[][]     math = {{"2X^2","4x"},{"q2","a2"},{"q3","a3"},{"q4","a4"},{"q5","a5"},
            {"q6","a6"},{"q7","a7"},{"q8","a8"}};

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (f.getText().equals(math[ques][1])) {
            correct = true;
        } else {
            incorrect = true;
        }

        f.setText("");

        if(ques<7)
            ques++;
        else
            ques = 0;

        System.out.println(ques);
        //I can see the change here
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){//called whenever refreshed...
        System.out.println(ques);
        // But now outside of the action performed the ques and the correct incorrect do not change

        if(correct)
            b.move();
        if(incorrect)
            b.move2();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameRunner gui = new GameRunner ();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        button = new JButton("Guess");
        f = new JTextField(15);

        button.addActionListener(this);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Derivative Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        JPanel pan = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel pan2 = new GameRunner();
        JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();
        pan3.add( f);
        pan3.add(button);
        pan3.setBackground(new Color(80, 218, 213));
        pan.add( pan3,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pan.setBackground(new Color(80, 218, 213));
        frame.add(pan2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, pan);
        frame.setSize(700, 760);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you have two boolean values, `correct` and `incorrect`, for essentially the same thing.

Comment: two different move methods

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you've actually got **two** instances of `GameRunner` here: the one you create in `main()`, and another one that you add to the JFrame. Since you only call `go()` on the one **not** in the JFrame, that instance's `paint()` method will never be called.

You need to refactor your code to eliminate that second stray `GameRunner` instance. While you're at it, you should also use `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`, and you should take any "business logic" (like those calls to `move()`) out of your painting code.

In other words, get rid of this line:

```
JPanel pan2 = new GameRunner();
```

Since you're already "in" an instance of `GameRunner`, you shouldn't be creating another one. Then to use the "current" instance of `GameRunner`, you can use the **this** keyword:

```
frame.add(this);
```

Edit- You also aren't telling your `GameRunner` `JPanel` to repaint itself after the button is clicked. You might want to add a call to `repaint()` in your `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: (For the OP who reads this answer) A [similar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295418/actionlistener-gets-default-values/).

Comment: thanks for the help, and yea it was a mess. I just threw things together to start